# Is it possible to buy a SIM card at Lyon airport?

Tags: france, airports, cellphones, lyon

I'm travelling to France and my port of entry will be Lyon airport.
If anyone's been to that airport, can you please tell me if it's possible to buy a prepaid local SIM card in the airport itself?

I did some research online but couldn't find anything valuable. Are there any shops or outlets that sell SIM card in Lyon airport?
Also, I'm arriving pretty late at night so I may not be able to purchase a SIM card from the local shops in the city.

Answer (score 4):

You can by a [prepaid SIM card by SFR](http://www.sfr.fr/telephonie-mobile/sfr-la-carte/welcome/). It is available in "Relay" shops where they mostly sell newspapers.

As you can see [on this page](http://www.lyonaeroports.com/en/shopping-services/shops?paginationPage=2), there are several Relay shops in the airport. They are all opened until 20:30 at least, 21h in some cases.

EDIT:
Beware, these Relay are located inside other stores :

- L'Occitane: cosmetics in terminal 2 (in "reserved zone")
- OL Store: Local football club merchandising in terminal 1 (in "public zone")
- Payot Librairie: bookstore in central "public" zone (level 1)

Here is a map extracted from Google Maps but I don't know this airport well enough to locate the arrival. 
[image: Map]

Comment: Thanks so much for this information! Can you please tell me if this is located in the arrival terminal?

Comment: See my edit. Hope it will be helpful.